# NSEvent commandKey not detected

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsevent

I'm trying to detect whether the command key is pressed, and for the life of me cannot figure out what is wrong with the following.  I've overridden a view to provide the code below:

```
- (void)flagsChanged:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    NSLog(@"flags changed in %@", self);
    BOOL commandKeyPressed = ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSCommandKeyMask);

    if (commandKeyPressed)
        NSLog(@"command key in %@", self);
}
```

I see the "flags changed" message whenever I press the command key, but not the "command key in" message.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `BOOL` is a `signed char`, so when you convert an `int` to a `BOOL`, you lop off all but the low 8 bits.  And in your case, the nonzero bit is not in the low 8 bits.  Instead, say

```
BOOL commandKeyPressed = ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSCommandKeyMask) != 0;
```

or just

```
if ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSCommandKeyMask)
```

Comment: These days it is: 

      BOOL commandKeyPressed = (theEvent.modifierFlags & NSEventModifierFlagCommand) != 0;

NSCommandKeyMask is deprecated.